# Using delimiter to get multiple words as one string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I don't really know how to explain what I'm asking but I'm having trouble using a delimiter to isolate a multi-worded string.

Example: For line

```
3 James De Santa 2.30 friend 2010
```

I am not sure how to write my delimiter to have

```
String firstName = scanner.next(); //This would be "James"
String lastName = scanner.next(); //This would be "De Santa"
String relationship = scanner.next(); //This would be "friend"
```

I've tried

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-z'-]+");
```

but that returns "De" and "Santa" as two separate strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: How would you specify the lastName is two words or single word ? You definitely need a delimiter like 3-James-De Santa-2.30-friend-2010

Comment: Do your last names *always* have two Strings? What are the rules of your parsing? Are you sure that you want to use a Scanner to do this parsing?

Comment: The last name is not always two words, which is what is causing the trouble. I am only allowed to use Scanner's Delimiter to parse the string.

Comment: *"I am only allowed to use Scanner's Delimiter to parse the string"* - Hint look a other Scanner methods; e.g. `hasNextDouble`.  And read your requirements again ... carefully.  See if you are misinterpreting them.

Comment: "Use the method .useDelimiter with the Scanner in order to find the end of the last name by looking for the next number value.  Be sure to reset the delimiter after it is used." I can easily get the numbers but I don't know how to get the first and last names to break up correctly.